# Using multiple texture atlases in glsl when using gl.DrawElements

Tags: opengl, textures, glsl

So I am making a fairly complex 2d game using modern OpenGL. Right now I am passing a VBO with model matrix, texture cords etc. for all of my sprites (it’s an “Entity” based game so everything is essentially a sprite) to the shader and using `glDrawElements` to draw them. Everything is working fine and I can draw many thousands of transformed sprites and I have a camera system working with zoom etc. However, I am using a single `sampler2D` uniform with my texture atlas. The problem is that I want to be able to use multiple texture atlases. How do other games/engines handle this?

The only thing I can think of is something like this:

I know I can have up to `GL_MAX_COMBINED_TEXTURE_IMAGE_UNITS` textures bound, but in order to draw them I need to set a `sampler2D` uniform for each texture and pass them to the shader. Then, in the shader I need to know which `sampler2D` to use when I draw. I somehow need to figure this out based on what data I have in my VBO (I assume I would pass a texture id or something for each vertex). Is this approach even possible using `glDrawElements`, is there a better/sane way to do this? I realize that I could sort my sprites by texture atlas and use multiple `glDrawElement` calls, but the problem is I need the sprites to be in a specific order for layering.

If this isn’t very clear please let me know so I can try and reword it. I am new to OpenGL so it’s hard for me to explain what I am trying to do when I don’t even know what I’m doing.

Comment: ...something like an [array texture](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Array_Texture)?  Core since 3.0!

Answer (score 0):

- bind atlas 1
- draw objects that use atlas 1
- bind atlas 2
- draw objects that use atlas 2
- ...

would be the simple way. Other methods tend to be over-complicated for a 2D game where performance isn't that important. When working with VBO's you just need an index-buffer for every atlas you use.